# Can't access a Codeigniter controller in sub folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have set up a folder with a controller in it: `controllers/admin/home.php`, but I get a 404 from the browser when I try to access it.

This is my routes file:

```
$route['employers'] = "employers/home";
//$route['employers/dash'] = "employers/dash";
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

This is the controller file:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class home extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();

        /*
            enable profiler
        */
        //$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);     

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('ion_auth');
        $this->load->library('session');

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->load->helper('layout');
    }
}
```

`.htaccess` seems fine standard. Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the address how you access the controller via your browser.

Comment: By the way: The routes are definitely not related in this case if this is all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note some things:
**1) Routes are executed in the order they're written**, and your custom routes MUST follow the default ones. So, it should be:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['employers'] = "employers/home";
```

This if your controller "home" is inside the folder "employers".

**2) Controllers don't need** all that stuff you wrote, indeed you don't even need **to call the parent constructor** unless you're planning to load libraries and resource for the whole controller's methods (which can be achieve also by autoloading them in the autoload.php file), so it could simply be:

```
file: application/controllers/employers/home.php

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
       // this is the method you're calling with your URL!
    }
}
```

**3)** As per above, and as already pointed out by @Wesley, with your url you're trying to access the INDEX method of your controller HOME in your subfolder EMPLOYERS. But **you didn't defined an index() method** (which is the one called by default if no other is supplied).
It seems, instead, that CI is trying to look for an employers controller and a home method; if it doesnt find it, but you have a employers folder, it tries to access the index method in the home controller in the employers folder. And, since it didn't find it either, you're getting the 404 page.

Hope I'm clear, otherwise just ask.

Comment: i have moved the controllers out of the sub folder and they seem to work fine... the sub folder just doesnt seem to do anything- when i made a duplicate of the sub folder and called it employers22 and accessed it from the browser it works fine- its down to the default controler for that folder that is the problem. (i think)

Comment: Did you set an index() method in your controller? it shoud be working, especially since you said that if you give it another name it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You failed to say how you were trying to access it via url. It should be:

```
{YOUR_BASE_URL}admin/home
```

... followed by optional URL segments (`/method/param1/param2/etc`).

Without the additional segments, this would by default load the `index` method. However, since you don't have **any** methods defined, there's nothing to load.

If this still fails after you define a method, move the controller file out of the sub-directory for starters, and make sure it works.

Comment: i have defined the index methods and so on- i just thought including the constructor may be a problem.

Comment: And what happened when you moved the controller file out of the sub directory, how are you accessing it via url, and do you get a server 404 or a CI 404?

Comment: tried moving out of the sub dir as well and it works fine. so am still lost

Comment: Well you still haven't answered the important question of *how* you are trying to access it via URL... It's easy to get help if you provide enough details - remember that for your next question. Playing guessing games is not fun.

Comment: i got a ci 404, can i log routes or run the profiler to see how the files are being accessed?